# How can I add a link to this html code?

Tags: css, html

`<a title="xyz" rel="simplemodal[examples]" href="images/x_big.jpg">`

Right now, I'm clicking a pic which is allowing me to open a big image (modal window) with the above line and, with the title xyz but, I also want a link (for example, google)?

Thanks!

Edited-
I think my question was wrongly interpreted or I didn't ask correctly anyway..
Right now when I click on a small pic, I get a modal window with the bigger version of the same pic and, a title (xyz) on top of it.
I want to know how can I add a link to some website in the same line of code. I'm confused as a href is already used above!

Thanks!

Comment: please show your efforts.. may be the html and css code?

Answer (score 2):

Add `target="_blank"`

`<a title="xyz" rel="simplemodal[examples]" href="images/x_big.jpg" target="_blank">`

Comment: `new window != new tab` but I think this is what OP wants.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes that's what i thought also.

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute `target` and set it to: `_blank` like here:

```
<a target="_blank" title="xyz" rel="simplemodal[examples]" href="images/x_big.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use target="_blank" property,

```
 <a href="link" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document.

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

More about target attributes,

```
    _blank  Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
    _self   Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
    _parent     Opens the linked document in the parent frame
    _top    Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
    framename   Opens the linked document in a named frame
```